# Is there a standard function signature for the digital signature "verify" function?

Tags: language-agnostic, cryptography, digital-signature, api-design, method-signature

Is one of these (or something else) more standard than the alternatives?

```
verify(message, signature, publicKey)
```

vs

```
verify(signature, message, publicKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
verify(publicKey, message, signature)
```

and there is objective reasoning behind it. Normally you first have to provide the public key (e.g. in an `init` method in the case of Java, then the data itself (e.g. in an `update` method) and finally you `verify` the actual signature. Note that the `publicKey` is often static; I personally prefer those at the start of the method.

Likewise, the signature generation would be:

```
sign(privateKey, message): signature
```

as you can see, nicely symmetric.

---

And since you are asking for a standard:

```
RSASSA-PSS-VERIFY ((n, e), M, S)
```

where `(n, e)` is the public key. This is straight out of [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-29) describing the RSA Cryptography Specifications.